# Get check ins for a specific Facebook location (page)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I have a Facebook location (page) where users can check in.  I'm the administrator of this page.  Is there a way with the API to get a list of recent check ins with user ID's?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've looked at them or not, but as far as I can see from the documents, this is not possible.
The checkins connection for a page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ only gives you a count of all the checkins.

With a user access_token it will only return a users checkins or that of their friends (if the appropriate permissions have been granted). But you won't be able to get the user_ids of people you are not connected to.

Saying that you could try the following FQL query with a page access token.

```
 SELECT author_uid,checkin_id,timestamp FROM checkin WHERE target_id = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
 //where xxxxxxxxxxxxxx = your page id
```

Or try subscribing to realtime updates https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/#introduction

Unfortunately I can't test this as I don't have any pages set-up with a location specified

Comment: Just tested the FQL approach, returns an empty data array. Looks like its not possible. Thanks.